# Write .so lib on C for Lua

Tags: c, lua, shared-libraries

I want to write .so lib and use it in my Lua program. I can't understand which syntax .so lib should satisfy. I found staza like this in ssl.so luasec library:

```c
static luaL_Reg funcs[] = {
  {"compression", meth_compression},
  {"create",      meth_create},
  {"info",        meth_info},
  {"setfd",       meth_setfd},
  {"setmethod",   meth_setmethod},
  {"copyright",   meth_copyright},
  {NULL,          NULL}
};
```

But what I should add to my C .so lib to make `funcs[]` (for example) visible from Lua program?

Comment: See [luaL_newlib](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_newlib) and [luaL_setfuncs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_setfuncs). See examples in the standard Lua libraries: read the [source](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/).